# How to modify a {% block %} within a template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an inclusion_tag called `content_blocks` defined. And I want to insert some js in to a `{% block%}`defined in base template.

**base.html:**

```
<html>
<body>

{% content_blocks %} # content_blocks tag will be used here..
...
...
{% block js %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>



# custom_tags.py

@register.inclusion_tag('tags/content_blocks.html')
def content_blocks():
    content_type = ... # some content type, obtained from somewhere else

    # todo: depending on 'content_type', insert some js in to {% block js %} 
    # how?

    .... other stuff
```

Is this doable? I can't put the js in tag template because then it outputs it middle of the page (This js code needs JQuery and it's loaded at end of the page)

Answer (score 0):

While you question is not quite clear, but i think what you want is what i have been doing lately, my setup is as follows:

- I have a base template with the following `block`s:  `page_content` for individual child templates's unique html/content and `page_js` for their custom scripts
- My jquery lies in the base template, and my `page_js` tag is after all other script includes in the bottom of the page.
- So in the child templates, for example `homepage.html` which extends the base template, i will also include the `{% block page_js %}` tag and what this does is override the empty one in the base template and put your scripts there and will be using the jquery on that base template since it inherits it